# Used the reactjs in vscode was report an error

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, format, highlight

use "jsx" grammar in visual studio code.
visual studio code report an error

[image]

Please help me.
Thanks!!!

Comment: User less than 10 rep can't upload an image. Try now, you should be able to do so.

Comment: You can at least share what the error is in the mean time. Errors should be included in your question as plain text anyway since images aren't searchable and are more difficult to read. [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: What is the error? Are your Prettier settings possibly messing with the syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbol "<" should appear in the same line with the tag name.

For example,
instead of doing that:

```
   return (     <
      button className="square"> {/*TODO*/} <
      /button>
   )
```

Do that:

```
  return(
    <button className="square"> 
         {/*TODO*/}
    </button>
)
```

If you want to split the tag to multiple lines,
you can do it like that:

```
      return (
        <button 
          className="square"
          id="id"
          onClick={someFunc}
        > 
             {/*TODO*/}
        </button>
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a button in the lower-right side of the VScode window (yours says "Javascript Standard Style"). If you click that you can select a different language mode. You want to select the one that works with React. You may also be able to select "Auto-detect" from the menu list.

For example, mine says "Javascript React"

[image]

The language mode can also be selected from the command-palette (CMD-Shift-p on Mac, not sure what it it is on other OS's, but you can also reach it from `toolbar > View`)..